How to find what is eating my CPU?
My Task manager shows a constant use of cpu on about 50%, as the image below shows :

BUT, when i try to check what process is using it, i see an idle time of 97% , how can it be ?
How can i diagnose what really is consuming my CPU ?


Look at the shape of the teeth marks in the CPU die? Sorry, just kidding. Are you experiencing lags or other symptoms of the CPU resource being consumed other than these? Or, to put it another way: what led you begin looking at your CPU values. Modern CPUs have various special-purpose cores that can be switched on and off based on the required loads. So a system under low load may shut down the high powered cores to use less energy, resulting in a higher apparent load but when you begin a more strenuous task the values will shift.

Looking at your screenshots, you've got applications using a lot of memory. Does ending these processes bring your apparent CPU loads down?

When you took this screenshot did you have a VM running?

@Ramhound Yes, a Virtualbox one

@music2myear i finished a lot of processes and the cpu went down, but i could not find what was the culprit

@delphirules - So you were running a VM. How many cores were assigned to the VM? What was the CPU utlization reported by the guess OS. The simplest explanation is that your VM, that you had running, is assigned a significant amount of your system resources. High CPU utlization while a VM is running is to be expected.

On the off-chance it is not showing in the graph, I mention that I had a process taking about 10% at idle that was related to a USB/MIDI footswitch (logidy) and expression pedal. My DAW and/or amp sims were not running, IIRC it was driver-level. Stack 2 more and you are at 30% potentially. I see ableton in your photo.

@Ramhound But in this case, will the Virtualbox process is not showing a high cpu usage ?

@delphirules - Task Manager has been known not to be 100% reliable and your question doesn’t answer my question about the VM.
